# How to design an square wave Oscillator Circuit with 1-20 MHz range?

Tags: capacitance, high-frequency, inductance, pulse, function-generator

I need a circuit that will generate square waves in a range of 1 to 20MHz. The circuit also should be adjustable in a scale of 0.05MHz for each step. There is no need for adjustments during the circuit operation.

It's possible to use some kind of LC circuit that i can simply replace the inductance/capacitance values?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it need to be accurate? Temperature stable?  You could search for inverter oscillators (aka relaxation oscillator).  RC's and an inverter. (74HC04 maybe)  Switch R and/or C for ranges.

Comment: A crystal-controlled DDS chip will generate that range of frequencies quite nicely, with good accuracy and repeatability. You can get evaluation boards and small modules that incorporate these chips all kinds of places these days.

Comment: @Dave: You should make that a real answer.  I was going to say something along those lines, but your comment covers it.  Elaborate a little and make a real answer out of it.

Comment: When you say "adjustable" I think most of us think you mean it would be adjusted during use. Do you really mean you could shut it down and take it back to the bench and replace components in order to adjust it?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, that's what I mean. There is NO need for  adjustments during the operation.

Comment: Then you need to answer George's questions if you want other answers besides DDS. Also, do you need tuning in discrete 0.05 MHz steps or would analog tuning be acceptable?

Comment: I need this circuit to run other primary coil in high-frequencies.
Analog tuning is fine because I need to calibrate the coil only once, but the waves frequency should be quite accurate and stable after those adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

A crystal-controlled DDS (direct digital synthesis) chip will generate that range of frequencies quite nicely, with good accuracy and repeatability. You can get evaluation boards and small modules that incorporate these chips all kinds of places these days. [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0095R21JM) is just one example.

Comment: DDS chip may be a good solution, thank you. I still wondering if I can use a simple LC circuit with some changes for my needs.

Comment: @MosheSimantov you will need some active components, such as a couple of (fast) inverters. DDS is cheap, small, reliable and precise. That's the best you can do

Comment: 40 MHz, ~$27. Have you used this? (or anyone.)  Can I get a sine wave and the quadrature up to 40 MHz ? (20 MHz would be enough.)

Comment: BTW, [here](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/High-Quality-New-AD9850-DDS-Signal-Generator-Module-0-40MHz-Test-Equipment-wholesale/1422043369.html) you can buy it much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a very simple and inexpensive oscillator with only logic gates, where the frequency and duty cycle can be determined by external components.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGqpUJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Here](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-118.pdf) is a very good application note where you'll find other topologies, even with a single gate, plus the formulas to calculate the frequency and duty cycle

Comment: How does this work if the first input is tied high?

Comment: Can you recommend for the right chips for my needs? is the CD4069 is suitable for this?

Comment: @MosheSimantov Yes, you can use the CD4069. Also, you can use CD4049, and CD40106 for Schmitt Trigger versions.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, you are rigth! I make a mistake in the diagram.... sorry! I will fix it ASAP.

Comment: @MosheSimantov Please checkout the modified diagram. Do not connect the input to high level.